# Angular material progression dialog

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is there an angular material component to show a list of current items in progress or those completed just like when you perform download below?  Or need to create my own?

I'm not asking about the progressLinear itself, I know that.  What I'm asking is a component that will group all current tasks in progress and completed tasks in a dialog where you can see a cancel button, show all processes, just like when you are downloading.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There are no components that I am aware of that have the exact behavior you are looking for. Other than the native browser support for downloads (which is not what you want). I think it would be really easy to create a reusable component to achieve what you are looking for. A directive that can track a list of tasks and callback to the appropriate cancel function on a button click.

There are several progress bars you could use. If you want angular-material... https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressLinear

Bootstrap has some options as well...
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I'm not asking about the progressLinear itself.  I'm asking if there's already a component that groups all tasks in progress, with the percentage and cancel option etc just like in the attached image.

Comment: Is the task always a download or is it any task and you are looking for a component that can track any task and register a cancel function?

Comment: any task not only download